# How to convert the Date object into "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" format in Java

Tags: java, android, date

I have the code below

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date curDate = new Date();
```

---

**What is happening** ::

For the `curDate` i get as: `Tue Nov 11 11:36:05 IST 2014`

---

**What i want::**

I want to convert into format: `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

---

**Question:**
How can I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
dateFormat.format(curDate)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `dateFormat.format(curDate)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(format1.format(d1));
```